# Windows Phone - How download a several files from web server and save on IsolatedStorage?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

My app does download of a JSON file (json.html) from a web server and saves the file on IsolatedStorage. This code works fine.

So, I need do the download from same web server, but of more files ("json.html", "json1.html" and "json2.html") and save on IsolatedStore also.

How adapt the code for more files?

The file must be saved with same name the file from web server (as in my code).

My code:

```
 private void sinc(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsolatedStorageSettings iso = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;



        if (iso.TryGetValue<string>("isoServer", out retornaNome))
        {
            serv = retornaNome;
        }

        else {
            MessageBox.Show("Configure um servidor antes de sincronizar os dados!");
            return;

        }

            order.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

            client = new WebClient();
            url = serv + "/json.html";
            Uri uri = new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenReadCompleted);
            client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
            client.OpenReadAsync(uri);


    }

    private void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        string strFileName = url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf("/") + 1, (url.Length - url.LastIndexOf("/") - 1));
        IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        //  Path Storage
        // *** If File Exists
        if (isoStore.FileExists(strFileName))
        {
            isoStore.DeleteFile(strFileName);

        }
        IsolatedStorageFileStream dataFile = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(strFileName, FileMode.CreateNew, isoStore);


            long fileLen = e.Result.Length;
            byte[] b = new byte[fileLen];
            e.Result.Read(b, 0, b.Length);
            dataFile.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
            dataFile.Flush();
            object lenghtOfFile = dataFile.Length;
            dataFile.Close();

            order.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            ProgressBar1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            MessageBox.Show("Arquivo salvo!");


    }
    private void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ProgressBar1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        this.ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

    }
```

Comment: So can't you run the last 6 lines of code from your sinc function in a for loop? You can store the different file names in an array, create the url as `url = serv + filename[I]` inside the loop. The same OpenReadCompleted handler will work for all the files.

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on and what have you tried? @Abhishek that alone won't work because there are variables outside of the scope of the method such as `url` that need to be internalized otherwise the async methods will probably ended up naming the files wrong.

Comment: @siva.k Right.. I didn't notice that. That can be handled though. As you mentioned, really depends on where OP is stuck.